# Grails Autocomplete With DependsOn doesn't work

Tags: grails, autocomplete, grails-plugin

I have this code in my .gsp:

```
<input id="selection1" type="hidden" name="selection1" value="test"/>
 <gui:autoComplete
  minQueryLength='2'
  queryDelay="0.2"
  id="corso"
  controller="utente"
  action="corsoAutoComplete"
  resultName="corsi"
  dependsOn="selection1"
 />
```

I use Grails-ui 1.2

My controller is that:

```
def corsoAutoComplete={
    println params;
    def corso = Corso.findAllByNomeIlike("%${params.query}%",[max:15,cache:true])
    corso = corso.collect{
        [id:it.id, name:it.nome]
        }
    def jsonCorso = [corsi:corso]
    render jsonCorso as JSON        
    }
```

println params doesn't return the value of input with id="selecion1"

why???

Answer (score 0):

1) Despite the example on the plugin's page I'm not sure that the Grails UI autocomplete `dependsOn` can be anything but *another* autocomplete control because it needs to subscribe to an "itemselect" event in the "depended on" control (look at the plugin source for InputTagLib.groovy)

2) If you change the "depended on" control to another autocomplete (they can be made to work like normal HTML selects), try using the following syntax for the `dependsOn` property:

```
dependsOn="[label:'(control name)',value:'(desired param name)',useId:(true to use select id value)]"
```

Also have a look at the grails ui demo that has working sample code for each of the components:
http://code.google.com/p/guidemo/